# postcss-svgo:: Non-whitespace before first tag

Tags: reactjs, node.js, postcss

I have a react project, with node v20.10.0 installed.
Before that I had Node v16.
Any way, once I installed the new node version, naturally I had to update npm packages etc.
after I finished, once I build the project, I got this error:

```
static/css/main.7ec157a5.css from Css Minimizer plugin
postcss-svgo:: Non-whitespace before first tag.

> 1 | %3csvg width='26px' height='26px' viewBox='0 0 26 27' version='1.1' xmlns='http:…
    | ^
 webpack://./src/@core/components/spinner/index.scss:1:0
```

the file index.scss only contains this code:

`.logo { width: 200px; }`

Please also note, that the svg file the error complains about is in a css chunk file. I do not know where is this file coming from.

I do not have the postcss-svgo package installed.

one last thing. I'm using Craco.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

I tried to uninstall related packages, such as sass and sass-loader. I tried various craco configurations, and I tried to search and delete the problematic svg file